# Compare and match arrays with different sizes

Tags: java

I have a couple of arrays with different sizes; say, array **A** and array **B**.

```
Array A
```

[chery, chery, uindy, chery, chery]

```
Array B
```

[chery, uindy]

Need to check whether the values present in **Array A** is available in **Array B** or not. In the above example, all the values in Array A is available in Array B. Please help this out with the Java code. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at ArrayUtils.contain()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your arrays to a `List` and then use the [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) method to see if a particular list contains all elements described in another list.

You would get better performance out of it if they were `Set`s instead.

Example:

```
List<String> firstList = Arrays.asList("chery", "chery", "unid", ...);
List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList("chery", "unid", ...);

System.out.println(secondList.containsAll(firstList));
```

If the performance of this method in particular is getting a bit dodgy, then consider converting the lists into `Set`s instead:

```
Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("chery", "chery", "unid", ...));
```

Comment: Personally I believe `Set` is a better fit here.  At least change `firstList` to a `Set`

Comment: If performance becomes a concern, then yes it makes perfect sense to do this as a `Set`.  The above is more illustrative rather than copy-and-paste valid code, but I'll amend my answer to include a conversion to `Set`.

Comment: Just saw a flaw of this logic: OP is asking `the values present in Array A is available in Array B or not`, which means he is trying to find, for distinct values of A and B, is B a superset of A.  Your answer is doing the opposite

Comment: At that point, it's a matter of reversing the direction of the `containsAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

In the example I am using integers but can be used for other types also with slight modifications. 
First put a loop on array A elements.

```
for(int i =0; i<A.length(); i++)
{
    //this loop will transverse with all elements in array A.
}
```

Now inside this for loop make another for loop which transverse through elements of loop B.

```
for(int i =0; i<A.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<B.length();j++)
        {
            if(A[i] == B[j])
                { System.out.println("this element is in array A and B"); }
        }

}
```

Now if you want to check if all elements of A are in B you can make a boolean. this boolean is true as long each element in A is found at least once in B. as soon as you find one element which is not present on both arrays you can exit.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your requirement, you are going to find out if `B` is a superset of `A` (I mean the distinct values).

This can be easily done by one line like this:

```
String[] aArr = {.....};
String[] bArr = {.....};

return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(bArr)).containsAll(Arrays.asList(aArr));
```

In brief, make `B` a `Set`, and check if `B set` contains all values of `A`

so, if `A = {Apple, Apple, Banana, Cherry}` and `B = {Apple, Banana, Cherry, Pineapple}`, it will return true (that's the behavior base on your description)

Answer (score 0):

For arrays of Strings :

```
for (String str : array1)
{
    System.out.println(ArrayUtils.contains(array2, str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is not a good data structure for doing this. A `Set` is better. So convert your two arrays to `Set` objects,  then simply use `Set.equals()`. Either do the conversion by creating new objects just before the comparison,  or use a `Set` everywhere.

Comment: conversation should actually be conversion here=)

Comment: dunno reason for downvote, but this is indeed the best answer here

Comment: I'd shy away from `Set#equals`; there's no guarantee that the condition of equality will always hold.  If one set were a proper subset of the other, they couldn't be equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

```
Set<String> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"chery", "chery", "uindy", "chery", "chery"}));
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"chery", "uindy"}));

System.out.println("Sets are equal: " +setA.equals(setB));
```

The `equals` method of `AbstractSet` says

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true
>   if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size,
>   and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This
>   ensures that the equals method works properly across different
>   implementations of the Set interface. This implementation first checks
>   if the specified object is this set; if so it returns true. Then, it
>   checks if the specified object is a set whose size is identical to the
>   size of this set; if not, it returns false. If so, it returns
>   containsAll((Collection) o).

Comment: Set equivalence isn't the best solution here.  The sample data shown makes you think that, but if one set is a proper subset of the other (that is, A  < B), this will not work.